# Radio Button can't select and deselect

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter, radio-button

My radiobutton cant select and deselect.I wanted to make only one can be choose.And it cant link well to next interface.These are my code.Please look at the radiobutton part.I give all my code so that you guys can see what happen.

```
import Tkinter 
import tkMessageBox
WindowBox = Tkinter.Tk()
WindowBox.geometry("250x200")
WindowBox.title("Welcome to E-UPSR")

level1="easy"
level2="moderate"
level3="hard"


Tkinter.Label (WindowBox, text="Username:").pack()

username1 = Tkinter.Entry (WindowBox)
username1.pack()

Tkinter.Label (WindowBox, text="Password:").pack()

password1 = Tkinter.Entry (WindowBox)
password1.pack()

student=[]


def read():
    if not username1.get() or not password1.get():
        tkMessageBox.showerror('Invalid', 'Empty username or password')
    else:
        addstudent = open ("student.txt", "r")
        lines = addstudent.readlines()
        addstudent.close ()
        i = 0
        while i < len(lines) - 1:
            # username and password are saved in two line, label and value are separated by ':'.
            # to get them we need to reed two line in each iteration and split with ':' to get the value (second result of spliting) then strip to remove end line.
            user = lines[i].split(':')[1].strip()
            password = lines[i+1].split(':')[1].strip()
            # test if the user is registred 
            if user == username1.get() and  password == password1.get():
                WindowBox.withdraw()
                MenuBox.deiconify()
                break
            i += 2  
    return

def register():
    WindowBox.withdraw()
    RegBox.deiconify()
    return

RegBox = Tkinter.Tk()
RegBox.geometry("250x200")
RegBox.title("register")

Tkinter.Label (RegBox, text="Username:").pack()

username2 = Tkinter.Entry (RegBox)
username2.pack()

Tkinter.Label (RegBox, text="Password:").pack()

password2 = Tkinter.Entry (RegBox)
password2.pack()
RegBox.withdraw()

def back():
    RegBox.withdraw()
    WindowBox.deiconify()
    return    


def save():
    if not username2.get() or not password2.get():
        tkMessageBox.showerror('Invalid', 'Empty username or password')
    else:
        addstudent = open ("student.txt", "a")
        addstudent.write('Username:' + username2.get() + '\n')
        addstudent.write('Password:' + password2.get()+'\n')
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Writing", "Done")
    return

MenuBox = Tkinter.Tk()
MenuBox.geometry("250x200")
MenuBox.title("MainMenu")

LabelName= Tkinter.Label(MenuBox, text="Choose Subject").pack()
MenuBox.withdraw()

MathBox = Tkinter.Tk()
MathBox.geometry("250x200")
MathBox.title("Math")
MathBox.withdraw()

BmBox = Tkinter.Tk()
BmBox.geometry("250x200")
BmBox.title("Bm")
BmBox.withdraw()

SnBox = Tkinter.Tk()
SnBox.geometry("250x200")
SnBox.title("Science")
SnBox.withdraw()

EasyBox1 = Tkinter.Tk()
EasyBox1.geometry("250x200")
EasyBox1.title("Eng")
EasyBox1.withdraw()

EngBox = Tkinter.Tk()
EngBox.geometry("250x200")
EngBox.title("Eng")
EngBox.withdraw()

EasyBox1 = Tkinter.Tk()
EasyBox1.geometry("250x200")
EasyBox1.title("Math Easy")
EasyBox1.withdraw()

ModerateBox1 = Tkinter.Tk()
ModerateBox1.geometry("250x200")
ModerateBox1.title("Math Moderate")
ModerateBox1.withdraw()

HardBox1 = Tkinter.Tk()
HardBox1.geometry("250x200")
HardBox1.title("Math Hard")
HardBox1.withdraw()




def Math():
    MenuBox.withdraw()
    MathBox.deiconify()
    return 
def Bm():
    MenuBox.withdraw()
    MathBox.deiconify()
    return 
def Sn():
    MenuBox.withdraw()
    SnBox.deiconify()
    return 
def Eng():
    MenuBox.withdraw()
    EngBox.deiconify()
    return
def back1():
    MathBox.withdraw()
    EngBox.withdraw()
    SnBox.withdraw()
    BmBox.withdraw()
    MenuBox.deiconify()
    return

def callback():
    radSel=radVar.get()
    if radSel == 0:win.configure(MathBox.withdraw,EasyBox1.deiconify)
    elif radSel == 0:win.configure(MathBox.withdraw,ModerateBox1.deiconify)
    elif radSel == 0:win.configure(MathBox.withdraw,HardBox1.deiconify)


radVar = Tkinter.IntVar()
rad1 = Tkinter.Radiobutton(MathBox,text=level1,variable=radVar,value=1)
rad1.grid(column=5,row=5)
radVar = Tkinter.IntVar()
rad1 = Tkinter.Radiobutton(MathBox,text=level2,variable=radVar,value=1)
rad1.grid(column=5,row=6)
radVar = Tkinter.IntVar()
rad1 = Tkinter.Radiobutton(MathBox,text=level3,variable=radVar,value=1)
rad1.grid(column=5,row=7)



Tkinter.Button (RegBox, text="Back", command=back).pack()   
Tkinter.Button (RegBox, text="Enter", command=save).pack()
Tkinter.Button (WindowBox, text="Register", command=register).pack()
Tkinter.Button (WindowBox, text="Proceed", command=read).pack()
Tkinter.Button (MenuBox, text="Math",command=Math,width=15).place(relx=.0,rely=.2)
Tkinter.Button (MenuBox, text="Bm",command=Bm,width=15).place(relx=.0,rely=.4)
Tkinter.Button (MenuBox, text="Science",command=Sn,width=15).place(relx=.5, rely=.2)
Tkinter.Button (MenuBox, text="Eng",command=Eng,width=15).place(relx=.5,rely=.4)
Tkinter.Button (MathBox, text="Back", command=back1).place(relx=.4,rely=.7)
Tkinter.Button (EngBox, text="Back", command=back1).place(relx=.4,rely=.7)
Tkinter.Button (BmBox, text="Back", command=back1).place(relx=.4,rely=.7)
Tkinter.Button (SnBox, text="Back", command=back1).place(relx=.4,rely=.7)
Tkinter.Button (MathBox, text="Start", command=callback).place(relx=.8,rely=.7)


WindowBox.mainloop()
```

Comment: For starters, your program must only create a single instance of `Tk`. You need to replace all but one of the calls to `Tk()` with `Toplevel`.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley can you give an example?

Comment: The only example is to literally replace `Tk()` with `Toplevel()` everywhere except for one instance.

Comment: Take a look at the examples on this page.  You have to supply a callback (command) function if you want to do something when a choice is made  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_radiobutton.htm

Answer (score -1):

Radiobuttons are not designed to be selected and deselected. What you are looking for are checkboxes. ([see the difference](https://delib.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/203430309-Radio-button-vs-checkbox-what-s-the-difference-))

PS: You probably should read another python Tk tutorial. Using Tkinter.Tk() multiple times is not the way this works.

Comment: The second sentence is "I wanted to make only one can be choose", which is exactly what radiobuttons are for.